# How to change ContentType for the error in ServiceStack?

Tags: rest, error-handling, servicestack

Is there any way to change the response content type when error occurred?

Changing contenttype in 'ServiceExceptionHandler' is not applied.

The problem is: when sending JSON back via an iframe transport, IE/Opera prompts for download.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is only related to the fact that IE/Opera asks to download the json then you need to understand that IE does not know what to do with application/json contents.You will need to set the CONTENT-TYPE for json as text/html so that IE should not ask to download.

> But from the REST perspective, you need to set the correct response
>   type which is application/json so that clients can process the
>   response accordingly.

If you want to get away from the annoying IE/opera download thing, then use some other browser/tool to test the response.

Google [chrome rest client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) is a good tool for basic REST testing. For advanced testing purposes I would advice using [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

Hope it helps!

Comment: unfortunately, I didn't find the way how to change content type(i.e. to text/html) in servicestack when error occurred, that is the question.